# Google App Engine: Account validation via email confirmation

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

My app does not use the Google Users service, but instead, I've created a custom Account kind to handle users:

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

What is the best method to handle user account verification via email? I'm fairly new to this, and I have not been exposed to how email verification would work.

I would guess that when an Account entity is created, an email would be sent via the mail module to the email provided during sign up. The email would contain a 'verify' link. What would this link look like, and how would it work?

Any tip on where to get started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an extra property "hashedLink" in Account,which will be a md5sum of random words. Send the "hashedLink" in email as /url/activate?link=hashedLink 
Whenever user clicks on the link, use the hashedLink to activate the account of the user.
You can use the same hashedLink attribute for "Forgot password" feature.

Comment: Thanks, Sandeep. I will try implementing this now. Just to be clear, this is how it should work: I am assuming that an account would have two states: `un-authenticated` and `authenticated`. Let's say that the default account is `unauthenticated` before the user clicks on `/activate?user=6236463746&hashlink=7328ehshsidhw9e8h98`. I set up a handler which `get(user, hashlink)`. If they match, the handler will switch the Account state to `authenticated`. Am I correct?